# std::ofstrean doesn't work with -O3

Tags: c++, fstream

The following code, simply

1) takes an input file name from the command line argument, say in.txt

2) append the file name to "cdf_"

3) open a file with new name cdf_in.txt

4) simply read each line from (a number in each line) and send it to the output file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  char *ben = argv[1];    // example: in.txt
  ifstream fin (ben);
  char res[30];

  char *o1 = "cdf_";
  strcat(res, o1);
  strcat(res, ben);
  ofstream fout (res, std::ofstream::out);   // will be cdf_in.txt
  cout << res << endl;

  uint64_t num;  uint64_t sum = 0;
  while (fin >> num) {
    fout << num << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

By running the program without any optimization, it runs normally. However, by specifying `-O3`, it fails to create the output file. Why???

```
$ g++ -o cdf cdf.cpp
cdf.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
cdf.cpp:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
$ ./cdf in.txt
cdf_in.txt
$ ls cdf*
cdf  cdf.cpp  cdf_in.txt  cdf.py
$ cat cdf_in.txt
10
5
3
2
1

$ rm cdf_in.txt
$ g++ -O3 -o cdf cdf.cpp
cdf.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
cdf.cpp:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
$ ./cdf in.txt
cdf_in.txt
$ ls cdf*
cdf  cdf.cpp  cdf.py
```

Why the `fout` doesn't work with `-O3`?

Comment: what happens if you replace all `char*` by `std::string`?

Comment: Sometimes, `-O3` may expose leaks that were hidden, or too low to be seen, at standard compilation. Check your program with Valgrind if you can to search for leaks.

Comment: The version is GCC-4.4.6

Comment: @vsoftco: the file name inside fstream should be char*

Comment: You are not checking if any of the files open correctly.

Comment: You can use `string::c_str()` to pass a `const char*` safely.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: is that really important? As I said, without checking and without using -O3 it is ok

Comment: If you can't open a file, is there any meaning in continuing with the program? For example, what is the meaning in doing the read/write loop if the output file can't be opened (which might happen considering your undefined behavior, which technically makes the whole program ill-formed). If something can fail, you should always check for failure, better get that good habit early.

Comment: You completely _ignored_ the warning. **Why?!**

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: well yes! but what is the relation between deprecated version and the O3? If there is a relation, then that means in old times (when that conversion was not deprecated), there was no O3!

Comment: @mahmood: No it doesn't. `-O3` has nothing whatsoever to do with the problem in your code identified by the warning that you ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `strcat(res, o1);` depends on `res[0] == '\0'`, which may be true, but isn't guaranteed (`res` is an uninitialized local, so its contents aren't known/specified).

Chances are that it's being initialized to zeros when you don't do optimization, but not when you do.

You could fix it by initializing `res`, or by using `strcpy` instead of `strcat` for the first item you want to copy there (but this still leaves possible buffer overrun problems, so see below for better alternatives).

Or, of course, you could write code that's more like C++ instead of C, and use `std::string` instead of arrays of char.

```
std::string fname("cdf_");
fname += argv[1];

std::ofstream fout(fname.c_str()); // just `fout(fname)` with a C++11 compiler
```

If you really want to write C-like code for some reason, it's probably easier to use `sprintf` in this case:

```
char res[30];

sprintf(res, "cdf_%35s", argv[1]);

std::ofstream fout(res);
```

Comment: FYI, if I initialize like `char res[30] = "a";` the same thing happen with `-O3`. No such file....

Comment: OK. The c++ method is preferred. Thanks

Comment: @mahmood: there's no question (at least in my mind) that the problem is in the code you're using to generate the file name. Once you generate the file name, you're passing a string to a `ctor` for `std::ofstream`, which is usually going to be exactly the same code regardless of optimization level.